# (Python)Object dict copy gets modified for no apparent reason

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self,dict):
        self.dict = dict

a = Object({1:"hello",2:"lol"})
b = Object(a.dict)
b.dict.pop(1) #remove the element with key 1

print(a.dict, b.dict)
>>{2: 'lol'} {2: 'lol'}
```

for some reason the "a" object's dictionary gets modified too.
I've tried the same thing with a different attribute, like an int variable, and the problem didn't happen. I really don't know what to do :(

Comment: You didn't create a copy of the dictionary anywhere, so now both objects are referring to the same dictionary object with their `.dict` attribute. This works exactly the same way with all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not copying the dictionary you are just pointing both a and b to the same dict, thats why its changing both.

you can use dict.copy() to create a shallow copy.

`b = Object(a.dict.copy())`

this will copy the dict but not any nested dictionaries, for that you need a deep copy.

```
import copy

b = copy.deepcopy(a.dict)
```